# lodash orderBy on nested property

Tags: lodash

I'm using `v4.11.0`.
I would like sort objects based on `milliseconds` property.
Here's the array :

```
[
    {
        "name": "bug12755.xml",
        "list": "bugs42",
        "start-date": "2015-09-14",
        "age": {
            "text": "7 months",
            "milliseconds": 18381227304
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "bug12922.xml",
        "list": "bugs42",
        "start-date": "2015-08-27",
        "age": {
            "text": "8 months",
            "milliseconds": 19936427304
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "bug13183.xml",
        "list": "bugs50",
        "start-date": "2015-08-27",
        "age": {
            "text": "8 months",
            "milliseconds": 19936427305
        }
    }
]
```

I'm missing something fundamental about the `iteratee` function. I have this but does not seem to sort the array. Thanks in advance!

```
 _.orderBy(list, function(item) {
            return item.age.value;
        }, ['desc']);
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It seems that you are ordering by the wrong property `value`.

```
_.orderBy(list, item => item.age.milliseconds, ['desc']);
```

Comment: Be careful anyone sorting with letters.  Lodash doesn't do natural sort order on letters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848030/lodash-how-to-do-a-case-insensitive-sorting-on-a-collection-using-orderby

Answer (score 43):

https://codepen.io/a2qube/pen/pKYrgN

A simple example on how you can use the Lodash: orderBy to sort based on inner attributes.

`hotels = _.orderBy(hotels, 'account.id', 'desc');`

Comment: this approach is much better as it's simpler and gets the job done with less complexity.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example on how you can sort by another property if one is undefined:

```js
import _ from "lodash";

const orderItems = (items) => _.orderBy(items, (item) => item.displayName || item.name, ["asc"]);
```

Referance:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36606220/5994546
- [lodash orderBy on nested property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36606105/5994546)