# Lodash : how to do a case insensitive sorting on a collection using orderBy?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873635/underscore-js-case-insensitive-sorting) but to achieve the same result, that is to get case-insensitive sorting, I need to use `orderBy` instead of `sortBy` since **it gives the ability to specify the sort order**.

The only way I found to achieve it was to create a cloned "middle" array mapped to lower case the `name` :

```
const users = [
  { name: 'A', age: 48 },
  { name: 'B', age: 34 },
  { name: 'b', age: 40 },
  { name: 'a', age: 36 }
];

let lowerCaseUsers = _.clone(users);

lowerCaseUsers = lowerCaseUsers.map((user) => {
  user.name = user.name.toLowerCase();
  return user;
});

const sortedUsers = _.orderBy(lowerCaseUsers, ['name'], ['desc']);

console.log(sortedUsers);
```

This seems really expensive and it will even be more complex with multiple sortings and dynamic properties names.

Is there a better idea ?

---

Here is a Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/i1ywyxjFctuNfHtPTcgG

Answer (score 245, accepted):

The [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#orderBy) specifies that you can pass a function as "iteratee":

> [iteratees=[_.identity]] (Array[]|Function[]|Object[]|string[]): The iteratees to sort by.

So you can do

```js
const users = [
  { name: 'A', age: 48 },
  { name: 'B', age: 34 },
  { name: 'b', age: 40 },
  { name: 'a', age: 36 }
];

const sortedUsers = _.orderBy(users, [user => user.name.toLowerCase()], ['desc']);
console.log(sortedUsers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This may fail on older browsers.

Comment: If you mean that this will throw a syntax error in browser not supporting ES6, then yes, of course. I'll leave converting the arrow function to a "normal" function (and `const` to `var`) as exercise to the reader.

Comment: @TheCaptan: there is no reason why it should not.

Comment: I'm attempting @TheCaptan's question with the following, but get a compiler error: `const sortedUsers = _.orderBy(users, [user => user[propToSort].toLowerCase()], ['desc']);`

Comment: @im1dermike: you probably want to use `.toString()` before calling to lowercase there, additionally if you want to use `property.something` for propToSort and similar you can use `_.get(user, propToSort)` (maybe this will help someone else)

Answer (score 25):

Ordering by multiple properties:

```
const users = [
  { name: 'A', age: 48 },
  { name: 'B', age: 34 },
  { name: 'b', age: 40 },
  { name: 'a', age: 36 }
]

const nameSorter = user => user.name.toLowerCase()
const ageSorter = 'age'

const sortedUsers = _.orderBy(users, [nameSorter, ageSorter], ['desc', 'asc'])
```

Answer (score 8):

You can combine Felix Kling example with _.get function to sort by dynamic nested attributes:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let test = [{ a: {b:'AA'}},{a: {b:'BB'} }, {a: {b: 'bb'}}, {a:{b:'aa'}}];

let attrPath = 'a.b';

_.orderBy(test, [item => _.get(item, attrPath).toLowerCase()]);
```