# Sort by converted item in Lodash orderBy without changing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have data like

```
let data = [
  {DATE: "2017-08-18", COUNT: "65", EVENT_NAME: "TAX_EXEMPTION_FAILURE"},
  {DATE: "2017-08-18", COUNT: "63", EVENT_NAME: "FRAUD_NOT_DONE"},
  {DATE: "2017-08-18", COUNT: "4451", EVENT_NAME: "FRAUD_ACCEPT"},
];
```

I want to sort by the number value of `COUNT`, like `65, 63, 4451`, as numbers and not strings. I can't change the data because it gets displayed in a table in the format it's in (I will sort `50%` data by `50`, but display `50%`, etc)

Based on [Lodash : how to do a case insensitive sorting on a collection using orderBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848030/lodash-how-to-do-a-case-insensitive-sorting-on-a-collection-using-orderby), I pass in `[item => parseInt(item)]` to `orderBy`.

the following script does not work:

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const orderBy = require('lodash/orderBy');
// import some from 'lodash/some';

function isNumber(item) {
  let isnum = /^\d+$/.test(item);
  return isnum;
}

function are_all_numbers(data, key) {
  let values = _.map(data, key);
  return _.every(values, isNumber);
}

let data = [
  {DATE: "2017-08-18", COUNT: "65", EVENT_NAME: "TAX_EXEMPTION_FAILURE"},
  {DATE: "2017-08-18", COUNT: "63", EVENT_NAME: "FRAUD_NOT_DONE"},
  {DATE: "2017-08-18", COUNT: "4451", EVENT_NAME: "FRAUD_ACCEPT"},
];

let order = 'descending';

let all_are_numbers = are_all_numbers(data, 'COUNT');
console.log('all_are_numbers:');
console.log(all_are_numbers);

if (all_are_numbers) {
    var orderByResults = orderBy(
      data,
      [item => parseInt(item)],
      ['desc']
    );
} else {
    var orderByResults = orderBy(
      data,
      prop,
      order === 'descending' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
    );
}

console.log(orderByResults);
```

It runs:

```
$ node test_script.js 
all_are_numbers:
true
[ { DATE: '2017-08-18',
    COUNT: '65',
    EVENT_NAME: 'TAX_EXEMPTION_FAILURE' },
  { DATE: '2017-08-18', COUNT: '63', EVENT_NAME: 'FRAUD_NOT_DONE' },
  { DATE: '2017-08-18', COUNT: '4451', EVENT_NAME: 'FRAUD_ACCEPT' } ]
```

Why isn't it sorting by `parseInt` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should tell orderBy to do the ordering by `item.COUNT`:

```
[item => parseInt(item.COUNT)],
```

```js
orderBy = _.orderBy;

function isNumber(item) {
  let isnum = /^\d+$/.test(item);
  return isnum;
}

function are_all_numbers(data, key) {
  let values = _.map(data, key);
  return _.every(values, isNumber);
}

let data = [
  {DATE: "2017-08-18", COUNT: "65", EVENT_NAME: "TAX_EXEMPTION_FAILURE"},
  {DATE: "2017-08-18", COUNT: "63", EVENT_NAME: "FRAUD_NOT_DONE"},
  {DATE: "2017-08-18", COUNT: "4451", EVENT_NAME: "FRAUD_ACCEPT"},
];

let order = 'descending';

let all_are_numbers = are_all_numbers(data, 'COUNT');
console.log('all_are_numbers:');
console.log(all_are_numbers);

if (all_are_numbers) {
    var orderByResults = orderBy(
      data,
      [item => parseInt(item.COUNT)],
      ['desc']
    );
} else {
    var orderByResults = orderBy(
      data,
      prop,
      order === 'descending' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
    );
}

console.log(orderByResults);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```