# Sort and aggregate at same time using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some models that are basically as:

Owner has many Things

Things have many uses

I want to sort Owners by the summing the amount of Thing's uses where uses.good = true.

Basically I have to conditionally filter out certain uses, get the length of the eventual array for each Thing and then sum those and sort by it.

This is the approximation I have so far:

```
let owners = await Owner.find().populate({
      path: 'things',
      populate: {
        path: 'uses',
        match: {
          good: true 
        }
      }
    }).sort({
      uses : -1
    }).exec()
```

Having issues with the sort, not sure if this is the best approach either or if I should use aggregate.

Comment: You could use aggregation for this but it will be messy since you have multiple collections to join. But another way might be to sort after you get your all your results and use something like [lodash.orderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36606220/1022914) to sort on the length of uses e.g. `return thing.uses.length`.

Comment: Not really an option, I'm using this to do pagination so I can't really return all the documents per page use.