# Order a javascript array by optional attribute using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have a javascript array. Something like this one:

```
let myObjects = [{
        'name': 'name 1',
        'date': '2017-04-15T22:00:00Z',
        'date2': '2017-04-12T22:00:00Z' },

      { 'name': 'name 2',
        'date': '2017-04-05T22:00:00Z' },

      { 'name': 'name 3',
        'date': '2017-04-05T22:00:00Z' },

      { 'name': 'name 4',
        'date': '2017-04-12T22:00:00Z',
        'date2': '2017-04-10T22:00:00Z' }];
```

I want to order `myObjects` by `date2`, but in case that the object does not have this attribute, it should be considered its `date` value.

I could just do it this way:

```
myObjects.map(function(obj){ if(!obj.date2){ obj['date2'] = obj['date']; }});
let orderedObjects = _.orderBy(myObjects, 'date2', true);
```

But I consider that it is a tricky solution. Could this be done just using the `orderBy` function without altering the original array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_.orderBy()` with an iteratees function. For each element destructure `date2`, and `date`, and return `date` if `date2` doesn't exist:

```js
const myObjects = [{"name":"name 1","date":"2017-04-15T22:00:00Z","date2":"2017-04-12T22:00:00Z"},{"name":"name 2","date":"2017-04-05T22:00:00Z"},{"name":"name 3","date":"2017-04-05T22:00:00Z"},{"name":"name 4","date":"2017-04-12T22:00:00Z","date2":"2017-06-10T22:00:00Z"}];
        
const orderedObjects = _.orderBy(myObjects, ({ date2, date }) => date2 || date, true);

console.log(orderedObjects);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**_orderBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy) with a callback function that checks upon the `date2` value if it exists otherwise upon `date` value.

This is how should be your call:

```
_.orderBy(myObjects, function(o) {
  return o.date2 ? o.date2 : o.date;
}, true);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let myObjects = [{
    'name': 'name 1',
    'date': '2017-04-15T22:00:00Z',
    'date2': '2017-04-12T22:00:00Z'
  },

  {
    'name': 'name 2',
    'date': '2017-04-05T22:00:00Z'
  },

  {
    'name': 'name 3',
    'date': '2017-04-05T22:00:00Z'
  },

  {
    'name': 'name 4',
    'date': '2017-04-12T22:00:00Z',
    'date2': '2017-04-10T22:00:00Z'
  }
];

let ordered = _.orderBy(myObjects, function(o) {
  return o.date2 ? o.date2 : o.date;
}, true);

console.log(ordered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can check **[lodash orderBy on nested property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606105/lodash-orderby-on-nested-property)** where it shows a similar use case.